# Cannot access old time machine backups in mac osx due to permissions

Tags: macos, time-machine

I can't access my old backups on my external HD because I'm getting permissions errors. I have no luck even with trying to change the settings via "Get Info" in Finder.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What are the exact errors?

Comment: "The folder 'Music' can't be opened because you don't have permission to see its contents."